# Initializing a sessionfactory after web application startup

Tags: spring, sessionfactory

in common, hibernate sessionfactory is created in spring configuration file (eg spring-dao.xml) like;

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="configLocation">
<value>file:src/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
</property>
</bean>
```

and then in dao,

```
<bean id="myProductDao" class="product.ProductDaoImpl">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

in web.xml, we put the config file (spring-dao.xml) in contextConfigLocation;

```
<context-param>  
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-dao.xml</param-value>  
</context-param>
```

when the application is started, datasource is injected to all dao beans.

This was the summary, what my problem is, I do not want spring to connect to database on application startup. I have an admin(responsible for opening db connection after startup) and an admin applet working on remote machine, which communicates with  web app servlet. database connection for web application should be opened if authentication is ok.

how can i achieve this goal?

Comment: Is it a real requirement that "dao objects should have a null sessionfactory", or you just want to disable database access until permission from admin applet?

Comment: Is it that you do not want to load the sessionFactory initially and want to load the sessionFactory only if the authentication is a success ?

Comment: Does it really matter if database connections are open or not if the client can't access the SERVLET unless authenticated/authorized? Seems a bit of an overkill (and kinda weird architecture).

Comment: hi, thanks for all your comments, I think I didn't explain myself very well; there should not be a database connection on application startup but sessionfactory should be injected to my dao repository beans. when admin (which is responsible for opening the database) introduces hisself to system by username-password, my datasource will be constructed by some information gathered from admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was not to hard; Create a datasource with no parameters initially, and then setting values after admin credentials ok.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
  <!-- Connection properties. All should be ommitted. -->
</bean>


// code below is called after admin login
    DataSource dS = context.getBean("dataSource");
    dS.setUrl("...");
    dS.setUserPass(adminPass);
```

Comment: hey.. did it worked properly ? and is it a recommended way to modify dataSource at runtime ?

Comment: hey, yes it works. Our db pass is encrypted and at system startup, only a web application initiator can login and decrypt it with his smartcard.

Answer (score 0):

Specify `lazy-init="true"` on the `mySessionFactory` bean and it will be initialized when your code tries to access it for the first time i.e. when the authentication is successful.

Comment: hi Pangea, when I do lazy init session factory, during service bean creation, it says "hibernate dialect must be set when no connection available", because my datasource properties will be set after authentication programmatically. Diaect is not known before. I need more sophisticated way to solve this issue I think.

Comment: @asyard I believe you will be using one db type (oracle, mysql etc) anyway so setting the dialect to the matching db type is ok.